# Remove loader from product view page

Tags: magento2, product, image, ajax, loader

Magento 2 adding page loading in product view page like this below in body tag

```
<body data-container="body" data-mage-init="{&quot;loaderAjax&quot;: {}, &quot;loader&quot;: { &quot;icon&quot;: &quot;http://local.com/static/frontend/Theme/default/en_US/images/loader-2.gif&quot;}}" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope" class="catalog-product-view  page-layout-1column">
```

how to remove this loader in the product view page alone.

```
.loading-mask{
    display: none!important;
}
```

The above CSS is not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below css?

```
.catalog-product-view .fotorama__spinner.fotorama__spinner--show {
  display: none;
}

.catalog-product-view  .loading-mask .loader img {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```